# spark-testing-base to write Java JUnit tests for Spark with Hive support

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark, hive

I am using https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base to write JUnit tests.
Check the following code:

```
public class MyTestSuite extends JavaDataFrameSuiteBase implements Serializable {
    ....
    @Test
    public void oneTest() {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File testData = new File(classLoader.getResource("testFile1.txt").getFile());
        JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc().textFile(testData.getAbsolutePath());
        ...
```

I can read my test data contained in /src/test/resources to an RDD, which makes it possible to run *mvn test*.

However, my goal is to test a class **HiveLoader(file_location_in_hdfs,  database_name, session)** which expects a file in HDFS as input and creates a Hive Table from it in a given database. The following fails:

```
    ....
    @Test
    public void oneTest() {
       File testData = new File(classLoader.getResource("testFile1.txt").getFile());
       HiveLoader loader = new HiveLoader(testData.getAbsolutePath(), "db_name", spark())
       ...
```

The Exception I get is:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string);

The file must be in HDFS. After trying many things I found this non elegant workaround:

```
    ....
    @Test
    public void oneTest() {           
        File testData = new File(classLoader.getResource("testFile1.txt").getFile());
        JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc().textFile(testData.getAbsolutePath());
        lines.saveAsTextFile("/desired_location_in_hdfs");          

        TripleTableLoader tt_loader = new TripleTableLoader("/desired_location_in_hdfs", "db_name", spark);
```

Basically, I read the file locally into an RDD and write it back to HDFS.

Is there a better solution to make this file available in HDFS which works for spark-testing-base?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the actual exception.